# Checkbox remove focus in listview items - Android 4.0.4 Samsung GT-P7500

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, android-listview, focus

I am having trouble removing the focus from checkboxes in list view items. Whenever i click the list item, the checkbox receives focus.

I am experiencing this problem on Android 4.0.4 Samsung GT-P7500. Newer versions dont have this issue.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:id="@+id/list_item_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="@dimen/medium_padding"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/category_checkbox"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:duplicateParentState="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

As you can see i tried with all available parameters that were recommended by stack answers:

For parent:

```
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

For checkbox:

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:duplicateParentState="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```